# saving a photo within a user form registration with spring boot and reactTs

Tags: spring

my goal is when i saving the user , saving also the photo path of selected photo , but i got this error

WARN 39548 --- [tp1641869855-27] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]

i'm passing a PumpAttendantDto and MultipartFile on the request

```
@PostMapping(value=EndPoints.ADD,consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
   public ResponseEntity<PumpAttendantDto> addPumpAttendant(@PathVariable Long stationId,@RequestPart("pumpAttendant") PumpAttendantDto dto,
                                                            @RequestPart("photoFile") MultipartFile photoFile)
   {
      PumpAttendantDto savedPumpAttendant = pumpAttendantServiceImpl.addPumpAttendant(stationId,dto,photoFile);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(savedPumpAttendant, HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }
```

```
@Transactional
    public PumpAttendantDto addPumpAttendant(Long stationId, PumpAttendantDto pumpAttendantDto,MultipartFile photo) {
        final ESSValidationResult validationResult = stationValidator.validateOnAddPumpAttendant(pumpAttendantDto);

        if (validationResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new ServiceValidationException(validationResult.getMessage());
        }
        pumpAttendantDto.setStationId(stationId);
        if (photo != null && !photo.isEmpty()) {
            String photoPath = savePhoto(photo);
            pumpAttendantDto.setPhoto(photoPath);
        }
        return create(pumpAttendantDto);
    }
    private String savePhoto(MultipartFile photo) {
        String fileName = "user_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";

        try {
            Files.copy(photo.getInputStream(), Paths.get(photoStoragePath + File.separator + fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return photoStoragePath + fileName;
    }
```

```
package com.teknokote.ess.dto;

import com.teknokote.ess.dto.base.ESSActivatableDto;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
public class PumpAttendantDto extends ESSActivatableDto<Long>{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String tag;
    private Long stationId;
    private String matricule;
    private String photo;
    private String phone;
    @Builder
    public PumpAttendantDto(Long id, boolean actif, LocalDateTime dateStatusChange,String firstName,String lastName,String tag,Long stationId,String matricule,String phone,String photo)
    {
        super(id,actif,dateStatusChange);
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.tag=tag;
        this.photo=photo;
        this.matricule=matricule;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.stationId=stationId;
    }
}
```

```
import {
  FormControl,
  FormErrorMessage,
  FormLabel,
  SimpleGrid,
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { createPumpAttendant } from "common/api/station-api";
import { PumpAttendant } from "common/model";
import {
  AddPumpAttendantModalProps,
  AddPumpAttendantModalRefType,
} from "common/react-props";
import { PhoneInput } from "components/Input/PhoneInput";
import UIInputFormControl from "components/UI/Form/UIInputFormControl";
import UIModal from "components/UI/Modal/UIModal";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import useFormValidation from "hooks/use-form-validation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useESSContext } from "store/ESSContext";

const AddPompisteModal = (
  props: AddPumpAttendantModalProps,
  ref: React.Ref<AddPumpAttendantModalRefType>,
) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const { selectedStation } = useESSContext();
  const { pumpAttendantFormValidationSchema } = useFormValidation();
  const { t } = useTranslation("dashboard");

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const form = useFormik<PumpAttendant>({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      tag: "",
      matricule: "",
      photo: null,
      address: "",
      phone: "",
    },
    validationSchema: pumpAttendantFormValidationSchema,
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("pumpAttendant", JSON.stringify(values)); // Convert values to JSON and append to FormData
          if (selectedImage) {
            formData.append("photoFile", selectedImage);
          }

          await createPumpAttendant(selectedStation!!.id, formData);
          form.setSubmitting(false);
          onClose();
          props.onSubmit();
        },
      });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      form.resetForm();
    }
  }, [isOpen]);

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    open() {
      onOpen();
    },
  }));

  const closeModalHandler = () => {
    form.resetForm();
    onClose();
  };

  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <UIModal
      title={t("attendant.modal.title")}
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onClose={closeModalHandler}
      onSubmit={() => form.handleSubmit()}
      isSubmitting={form.isSubmitting}
    >
      <form>
              <SimpleGrid columns={2} spacing={5}>
                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.firstName && !!form.touched.firstName}
                  label={t("attendant.firstName")}
                  fieldName="firstName"
                  name="firstName"
                  value={form.values.firstName}
                  onChange={form.handleChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.firstName}
                />

                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.lastName && !!form.touched.lastName}
                  label={t("attendant.lastName")}
                  fieldName="lastName"
                  name="lastName"
                  value={form.values.lastName}
                  onChange={form.handleChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.lastName}
                />

                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.tag && !!form.touched.tag}
                  label={t("attendant.tag")}
                  fieldName="tag"
                  name="tag"
                  value={form.values.tag}
                  onChange={form.handleChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.tag}
                />

                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.matricule && !!form.touched.matricule}
                  label={t("attendant.matricule")}
                  fieldName="matricule"
                  name="matricule"
                  value={form.values.matricule}
                  onChange={form.handleChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.matricule}
                />

                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.photo && !!form.touched.photo}
                  label={t("attendant.photo")}
                  fieldName="photoFile"
                  name="photoFile"
                  type="file"
                  onChange={handleImageChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.photo}
                />

                <UIInputFormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.address && !!form.touched.address}
                  label={t("attendant.address")}
                  fieldName="address"
                  name="address"
                  value={form.values.address}
                  onChange={form.handleChange}
                  errorMessage={form.errors.address}
                />

                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={!!form.errors.phone && !!form.touched.phone}
                  mb="20px"
                >
                  <FormLabel ms="4px" fontSize="sm" fontWeight="bold">
                    {t("attendant.phone")}
                  </FormLabel>
                  <PhoneInput
                    id="phone"
                    name="phone"
                    value={form.values.phone}
                    onChange={form.handleChange}
                    placeholder={t("attendant.phone")}
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.phone}</FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              </SimpleGrid>
            </form>
    </UIModal>
  );
};

export default React.forwardRef(AddPompisteModal);
```